# How to stop the MainActivity from being called first?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

In my AndroidManifest.xml file, I have two activities:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

According to the logic of my app, if I'm logged in, I'm redirected directly to the `MainActivity`, otherwise to the `LoginActivity`. First time I'm opening the app, `LoginActivity` is opened but in the background `MainActivity` is also called. How stop this from happening? But without making `LoginActivity` as the main activity?

Comment: Use 1 Activity for both of them, then decide what fragment to show.

Comment: You can use you splash screen to decide if the user has already logged in or not. Do the decision stuff in splash screen and launch the next screen (Login/Main) accordingly.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So you basically say that I should use a single activity containing two fragments and show each one of them according to the user status (logged-in or not logged-in)? Is there any other way I can stop the MainActivity to be called? Thanks!

Comment: @Ravi Thanks Ravi, I can do that but is there any other I can solve this without creating another activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I always adopt is to create a third Activity `SplashScreenActivity`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is nothing more than a Loading Activity where you can instantiate all the stuff you need across application and where you can make this logic.

You can, for example, call this in your `SplashActivity`'s `OnCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(/*logics to see if user is logged*/) {
      startActivity(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    }
    else {
      startActivity(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    }
    finish(); //finish the splash activity.
}
```

Another little trick :)

Link from PPartisan in comment: [How to implement SplashScreen](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

I always make this `activity` *Layout-less* so that you don't have that annoying "black screen flash" when you first launch your application. In order to do that, as you can see, I specified a `theme` in that activity's manifest where I `simply` set this:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

where that resource is nothing more than a `drawable` with a `background` (white background and logo in center, for example).

That way you won't have that black flash when you run your application.

Good luck!

Comment: Never thought about this. I'll try to implement your solution and get you back.

Comment: Specifying a window background is also the recommended technique for a splash activity, instead of inflating a layout - [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

Comment: Added the link in the answer so it is more visible, thanks! @JohansBormman good luck! let me know if it worked for you :)

Answer (score -3):

You should move the following code to your login activity but LoginActivity will be the main activity:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can also use one activity with fragments inside and choose which fragment to display to the user according to the login status. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Finally, as mentioned in comments, you can create a splash screen that check if the user is already logged in. But here again, the splash screen will be your main activity. See https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

Best

Comment: Yes, and then decide where to open MainActivity

Comment: "But without making LoginActivity as the main activity?"

Comment: @TimCastelijns That's no logic at all. The "Main" Activity is the activity that is started when your app is opened.

Comment: Hi and thnaks by I need without making the LoginActivity as the main activity.

Comment: "The "Main" Activity is the activity that is started when your app is opened." - and he doesn't want that to be the login activity

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, that's right. Thanks Tim for your comments.

Comment: I know. I just don't understand why it's a problem that loginActivity could be the "main" activity. I updated my answer to list three solutions.

Comment: It's a problem because why would you open login activity if the user is already logged in?

Comment: Just to check if it is and then redirect to the MainActivity. But I agree that heavy. The splashscreen seems to be the best solution imo.